# nginx with nodejs : 502 bad gateway error

Tags: node.js, nginx, digital-ocean

so my app is written in nodejs and am using digitalocean droplet ( 2GB RAM | 1 CPU | 50gb SSD )

so I am getting the error as mentioned in the title only for one particular GET request. That GET requests processes data and renders a PDF file.

When i checked the nginx error logs, I see three lines of error throw up each time this URL is hit. Following are the errors

- upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream
- connect() failed (111 connection refused) while connecting to upstream
- no live upstreams while connecting to upstream

So, I started my research on these errors, and as suggested tried a lot of configuration changes in my nginx config file like

- adding increased read timeouts, etc
- adding increased proxy buffering
- disabling gzip
- adding an upstream block and such

This is my first time using nginx. I followed a youtube tutorial to deploy my app on a domain and then add a SSL certificate as well (*though have to admit I do understand now the basic concepts of how reverse proxy works and configuring after spending two full days trying to troubleshoot this problem, so I wonder what is it that is causing this issue*).

Before this I had deployed the app on the free tier of heroku and I faced no issue with this GET request on this particular URL.

Following is my current configuration file. It is at this path

> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
upstream localhost:3000 {
    zone upstreams 64K;
    server 127.0.0.1:3000 max_fails=0 fail_timeout=2s;
    keepalive 8;
}

server {
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name digitalawb.in www.digitalawb.in;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        proxy_read_timeout 90;
        proxy_buffering on;
        proxy_buffer_size 4k;
        proxy_buffers 24 4k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 8k;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 2048m;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 32k;
        proxy_redirect http://localhost:3000/ https://digitalawb.in/;
    }
    
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/digitalawb.in/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/digitalawb.in/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}

server {
    if ($host = www.digitalawb.in){
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    if ($host = digitalawb.in){
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name digitalawb.in www.digitalawb.in;
    return 404;
}
```

Also following is the content of the nginx.conf file which is at the following location

> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    #multi_accept on;
}

http {
    # Basic Settings

    sendfile on;
    top_nopush on;
    top_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    #SSL settings

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    #Logging settings

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    #Gzip settings

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+res text/javascript;

    #virtual host configs

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Following are my nodejs code details

1. Main function

```
exports.boxSticker = async(req, res, next) => {
    try{
        let orderId = req.params.orderId
        let userId = req.user.id

        let order = await Order.findById(orderId).populate('client').exec()
        let user = await User.findById(userId)

        const doc = new PDFdocument({             
            autoFirstPage: false
        })

        if(order.boxDetails.length == 0){
            return res.render('error', {message: `No Box Details added. Please add Box Details first before generating AWB`, statusCode: '400'})
        }

        const canvas = createCanvas()
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d')

        JsBarcode(canvas, order.awbNumber)
        
        canvas.toBuffer((err, buffer) => {            
            if(err) next(err)
            fsPromises.writeFile(`box_${order.awbNumber}.png`, buffer)            
            .then(() => {
                for(let i = 0; i < order.numberOfBoxes; i++){            
                   doc.addPage()
                   boxstickergenerate(i, doc, order, user)
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => next(err))
        })    
                
        res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf')
        res.set({ 'Content-Disposition': `inline; filename=boxsticker_${order.awbNumber}.pdf` })
        
        stream = doc.pipe(res)                                                      
        doc.end()                      
        
        stream.on('finish', () => {            
            fs.unlink(`box_${order.awbNumber}.png`, (err) => {
                if(err) next(err)                                        
            })
        })       

    }catch(err){
        next(err)
    }
}
```

2. boxstickergenerate function

```
exports.boxstickergenerate = (current, doc, order, user) => {
  
  doc.info['Title'] = `boxsticker${order.awbNumber}`

  doc    
    .fillColor('black')
    .rect(40, 75, 150, 30).fill()

    .lineWidth(1.5)
    .moveTo(40, 120)
    .lineTo(560, 120).stroke()

    doc
    .fillColor('white')
    .font('Helvetica-Bold')
    .fontSize(20)
    .text(order.service, 40, 80)

    doc.fillColor('black')
    .font('Helvetica-Bold')
    .fontSize(11)
    .text('FROM', 40, 140)
    .font('Helvetica')
    .text(order.consignor, 40, 155)
    .text(`${order.consignorAddress1}, ${order.consignorAddress2}, ${order.consignorCity}, ${order.consignorState}, ${order.consignorPincode}`, 40, 170, {width: 350, align:'left'})    
    .font('Helvetica-Bold')
    .text(order.origin, 40, 215)
    .font('Helvetica')
    .text(`TEL NO: ${order.consignorContactNumber}`, 40, 230)

    .lineWidth(1.5)
    .moveTo(40, 260)
    .lineTo(560, 260).stroke()

    .font('Helvetica-Bold')
    .fontSize(16)
    .text(`BOX NO ${current + 1}/${order.numberOfBoxes}`, 465, 140, {width: 100, align:'left'})
    .rect(440, 160, 115, 30).fill()
    .rect(440, 210, 115, 30).fill()
    .fillColor('white')
    .fontSize(11)
    .text(order.client.username, 445, 165)
    .text(order.service, 445, 215)

    .fillColor('black')
    .font('Helvetica-Bold')
    .fontSize(16)
    .text('TO', 40, 270)
    .font('Helvetica')
    .text(order.consignee, 40, 290)
    .text(`${order.consigneeAddress1}, ${order.consigneeAddress2}, ${order.consigneeCity}, ${order.consigneeState}, ${order.consigneePincode}`, 40, 310, {width: 450, align:'left'})
    .font('Helvetica-Bold')
    .text(order.destination, 40, 370)
    .font('Helvetica')
    .text(`TEL NO: ${order.consigneeContactNumber}`, 40, 390)

    .lineWidth(1.5)
    .moveTo(40, 410)
    .lineTo(560, 410).stroke()

    .fontSize(14)
    .text(`SHIPMENT DATE:`, 40, 430) 
    .text(moment(order.bookingDate).format(shortDateFormat), 160, 430)
    .text(`SHIPMENT WEIGHT: ${order.chargeableWeight}`, 40, 450)
    .text(`NO OF BOX: ${order.numberOfBoxes}`, 40, 470)
    .text(`WAYBILL NO: ${order.awbNumber}`, 300, 450)

    //.image(`box_${order.awbNumber}.png`, 265, 490, {width: 80, align:'center'}) 

    .lineWidth(1.5)
    .moveTo(40, 550)
    .lineTo(560, 550).stroke()

    .text('Office Purpose Only', 230, 570, {width: 150, align:'center'})
    //.image(`box_${order.awbNumber}.png`, 265, 590, {width: 80, align:'center'}) 

    .lineWidth(1.5)
    .moveTo(40, 650)
    .lineTo(560, 650).stroke()

    .text(user.username, 230, 670, {width: 150, align:'center'})
        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

are you using pm2 with --watch? That was actually my issue, all the things around the internet is to increase your timeouts in the Nginx config file, I tried everything, and I didn't realized that the issue was because I  was uploading a file, therefore changing a folder in the process, so pm2 will restart my app right before sending the response I was expecting in the front end. I hope this give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved your problem or not but I had the same issue and found a solution that is not the same as above (but it could be this one too).

My problem was coming from the fact that the subdirectory where the file was generated didn't not exist on the new server.
Worked on my local machine since I had created the subdir, I simply created the subdirectory in the correct path that was needed to create the file and it worked like a charm afterwards.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).